# I cannot link with gcc-7

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, linker, gcc7

I have 3 files:
`tester.c`, `knnring_sequential.c`, `knnring.h`.

I compile them with the sequence:

```
gcc-7 -c knnring_sequential.c -o knnring_sequential.o
ar rcs knnring_sequential.a knnring_sequential.o
gcc-7 -o tester tester.c knnring_sequential.a
```

When I am trying to link with gcc-7, I get the following error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___asan_init", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_00099_0_knnring_sequential.c in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
  "___asan_report_load4", referenced from:
      _insert in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _quickSelect in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _quickSort in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _kNN in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
  "___asan_report_load8", referenced from:
      _insert in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _quickSelect in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _quickSort in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _compute_distances in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _kNN in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
  "___asan_report_load_n", referenced from:
      _kNN in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
  "___asan_report_store4", referenced from:
      _insert in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _kNN in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
  "___asan_report_store8", referenced from:
      _insert in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _compute_distances in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
      _kNN in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
  "___asan_version_mismatch_check_v8", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_00099_0_knnring_sequential.c in knnring_sequential.a(knnring_sequential.o)
```

The code can be found here https://github.com/alextsigilis/knnring/blob/master/src/knnring_sequential.c

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  Regardless of whether you are or not, the problem appears to be a missing library, or an incomplete library, for the ASAN (Address Sanitizer) portion of GCC.  Where did you get the `gcc-7` from?  Have you been able to compile and link any other code with it?  Are you sure you've shown all the options you used?  (If so, why aren't you using `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`?  They help prevent lots of problems.)